# using HTML from my wix page to create another site

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a website for my band to practice and learn new things. My band already has a site through wix. Is it possible to write a script on the new page to tell it look at the first pages html and load that then use css and js to restyle and add features? that way when the content on the first page changes it will be loaded into the second page.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help] useful when it comes to [ask], and this question [checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and be included in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I do web work and I have got this question a lot from people who use site builders.

All in all, Wix's does not have a way to export or download your source code, as for your website to work, it needs to be on Wix's servers. Wix is advertised as Software-As-A-Service. For Wix, they are a web hosting/building service.
If you were to make a program to see the source code, you would spend more time making the program then getting use out of it. I do not mean to be rude saying that, but there are easier ways of building the site.

For instance, If you want to build the site from scratch and want to have a web builder, you could look at using WordPress. It's free and open source. My website in my bio runs on WordPress and the User interface/editor is very user friendly!

If you did want to play around with it and get it locally set up on your computer, you can download XAMPP to act as a "host" for your "site" on the computer and let you edit your WordPress page.

[How can I run WordPress locally on a computer?](https://themeisle.com/blog/install-xampp-and-wordpress-locally/)

Of course, if you do decide to publish your site, I would recommend Namecheap as I use their hosting services too! They have WordPress that comes with their host and is a 1-click install.

I apologize if I got wordy in my answer. I honestly hope this information helps! If you ever need help with your site, my site has my contact info!

P.S: Welcome to Stack overflow! Glad to see another user on here :)

Comment: Figures. Thanks for taking the time to clarify. It seemed so simple that the html would be retrievable in some way. Ill just keep reading before coming up with any more bright ideas.